# Why float division is faster than integer division in c++?

Tags: performance, c++11, x86, floating-point, division

Consider the following code snippet in C++ :(visual studio 2015)

**First Block**

```
const int size = 500000000;
int sum =0;
int *num1 = new int[size];//initialized between 1-250
int *num2 = new int[size];//initialized between 1-250
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum +=(num1[i] / num2[i]);
}
```

**Second Block**

```
const int size = 500000000;
int sum =0;
float *num1 = new float [size]; //initialized between 1-250 
float *num2 = new float [size]; //initialized between 1-250
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum +=(num1[i] / num2[i]);
}
```

I expected that   first block runs faster because it is integer operation . But the Second block is considerably faster , although it is floating point operation . here is results of my bench mark : 
Division:

```
Type    Time
uint8   879.5ms
uint16  885.284ms
int     982.195ms
float   654.654ms
```

As well as floating point multiplication is faster than integer multiplication.
here is results of my bench mark :

Multiplication:

```
Type    Time
uint8   166.339ms
uint16  524.045ms
int     432.041ms
float   402.109ms
```

My system spec: CPU core i7-7700 ,Ram 64GB,Visual studio 2015

Comment: Division speed depends on the values. You need to initialize your values with something (e.g. `rand()`) for the benchmark to be meaningful.

Comment: Is not code doing a whole lot of division by 0?  (potential kicking off exception handing with integers math) Try non-zero divisors.

Comment: @chux Integer division by 0 terminates the application.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin C does not require a division by zero to terminate the program - even if a common result.  IAC, the code compare would be less distracting if the quotient was well defined, (no overflow/ div 0)

Comment: @Maxim ,chux : thanks for reply. as i said in my question its a code snippet and its not whole program. in my main code i initialized my vars by  values between 1-250.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/85v6SB - you can get single instructions for some floating point ops, that can be quicker.

Comment: @chux I run my applications on Linux, rather than in an abstract C machine. On Linux integer division by 0 causes `SIGFPE`. I am pretty sure integer division by 0 on Windows also terminates your application.

Comment: In second block, changing `int sum` to `float sum` makes it even faster. But the result may be different because the fractional part doesn't get truncated on each addition.

Comment: This question about performance in C++ lacks information about the compiler and compilation flags used.  As such, it is a poor question.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: For the record, integer division by 0 on **x86-64** (and x86-32) Linux causes SIGFPE.  Some other ISAs, like ARM and AArch64, don't ever raise an exception on integer division, but it's still not fast.  (Apple M1 does have a pretty high performance divider).  x86 doesn't have a way to get the hardware not to trap on integer division, ARM doesn't have a way to make it trap.  Most OSes will deliver a signal or equivalent to a process that causes an arithmetic trap, with the default action (if no signal handler) being to kill the process.  (POSIX requires SIGFPE if any signal).

Comment: How did you compile this?  "Release" mode, like `-O2`? Unfortunately none of GCC / Clang / MSVC vectorize with `divps` to do four FP division for the same cost as one. https://godbolt.org/z/1v6r6Pbb3 With `int sum`, `sum += float` compiles to converting `sum` to float, FP add, and convert back, which is pretty high latency for a loop-carried dependency, should be worse than integer division throughput on your Kaby Lake CPU.  (One per 6 cycles: https://uops.info/).  `divss` throughput is only one per 3 cycles on the same CPU, so it's not the bottleneck if this is actually the code you compiled.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the insightful comments, Peter. Learned a lot from you, pushing IPC of my performance critical compute code paths to 4.1 and beyond on Zen3. Feel like I need more general purpose and vector registers than x86-64 has to offer. Want faster division, faster xmm to flags and general purpose register transfers, shorter instruction encoding.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Yeah, AVX-512 is very nice for a lot of things like more registers, and `ktest` / `kortest` for fewer uops to branch on SIMD conditions sometimes, but can be expensive to get data in and out of `k` registers. And it's super bad for instruction-length. :/  And Intel seriously dropped the ball in terms of it being widespread any time soon, and it's still going to be a while before they get AVX10 for the 256-bit subset of AVX-512.

Comment: @PeterCordes Getting data into and out of SIMD registers makes you feel like you are using another alternative ISA that just doesn't want to fit and cooperate. I am starting to look for another architectures, x86-64 feels like glorified 4004. I need more registers, playing nicely with each other, low latency and short encodings. These 16 GP registers are a joke.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: AArch64 is pretty nice, and Apple's implementation has fast integer division.  It lacks a `vpmovmskb` equivalent, although there are some tricks you can do.  (Unless you can branch on SVE masks; I haven't looked at SVE much compared to NEON.)  Yeah, x86-64 definitely has a lot of warts, and the cost to fix them (with stuff like APX for REX2 or EVEX on scalar integer instructions for 3 operands and 32 integer registers) is a code-size increase, although saving some `mov` insns helps.  And REX2 is only 2 bytes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Floating point number division is faster than integer division because of the exponent part in [floating point number representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats). To divide one exponent by another one plain subtraction is used.

`int32_t` division requires fast division of 31-bit numbers, whereas `float` division requires fast division of 24-bit mantissas (the leading one in mantissa is implied and not stored in a floating point number) and faster subtraction of 8-bit exponents.

See an [excellent detailed explanation how division is performed in CPU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/421366).

It may be worth mentioning that SSE and AVX instructions only provide floating point division, but no integer division. SSE instructions/intrinsincs can be used to quadruple the speed of your `float` calculation easily.

If you look into [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), for example, for Skylake, the latency of the 32-bit integer division is 26 CPU cycles, whereas the latency of the SSE scalar float division is 11 CPU cycles (and, surprisingly, it takes the same time to divide four packed floats).

Also note, in C and C++ there is no division on numbers shorter that `int`, so that `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are first promoted to `int` and then the division of `int`s happens. `uint8_t` division looks faster than `int` because it has fewer bits set when converted to `int` which causes the division to complete faster.

Comment: Whlie there is no division below int, under as-if compilers are free to divide using sub-int division so long as the results are the same.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That is conceivable. Do you have an example that demonstrates it? Because I haven't seen that happen in practice, see, for example https://godbolt.org/z/ujcxvT