# How to generate huge uniform distribution over small range of int in C++ fastly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, boost, openmp

Edited: to clarify high dimension meaning

My problem is generating N size array or vector(corresponding to math N dimensional vector), N is huge, more than `10^8`, each dimension lies at i.i.d uniform distribution over `1~q`(or `0~q-1`), where q is very small, `q<=2^4`. And array must be good statistically. So the basic soltuion is

```
constexpr auto N = 1000000000UZ;
constexpr auto q = 12;
std::array<std::uint8_t, N> Array{};
std::random_device Device{};
std::mt19937_64 Eng{Device()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> Dis(0, q);
std::ranges::generate(Array, [&]{return Dis(Eng);});
```

But the problem lies in performance, I have several plans to improve it:

1. because `s=q^8<=2^32` so, we use

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> Dis(0, s);
```

add decompose the result `t<q^8` into 8 different `t_i<q`, but this decomposition is **not straightforward**, and may have performance flaw in decomposition.

2. use `boost::random::uniform_smallint`, but I don't know how much improvement will be? this cann't be used together with method 1.
3. use multi-threading like `openmp` or `<thread>`, but C++ PRNG may not be **thread-safe**, so it's hard to write to my knowledge.
4. use other generator such as `pcg32` or anything else, but these are not **thread-safe** as well.

Does anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: *Why* do you need to create this large array? What is the actual problem is this large array supposed to solve? I think that's a more interesting problem to ask about, and which might have other solutions that doesn't requires such large arrays (that won't fit on the stack anyway if you define `Array` as a local variable). Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Always ask about, or at least include, the original and underlying problem you attempt to solve with the shown code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this problem indeed has physics background, need N^3 particles to simulate, N^3 is very large providing N is large, and q is state of particle. As far as I now, all solutions need huge dimensional array to represent particles' state.

Comment: I don't see an N-dimensional array in your code, only a 1-dimensional array of size N.

Comment: @JaMiT In physics you often talk about n-dimensional vectors( a vector in a n-dimensional vector space) so N-dimensional is meant in this way.

Comment: @Wongboo How fast do you expect your program to be? Your code with 10^9 elements runs in 5 seconds for me, which seems pretty fast for creating 1GB of random data.

Comment: Thread safety can be solved simply by having multiple prng.

Comment: @gerum Last I checked, this site is for comp sci Q&A, not physics Q&A. Questions should use the terminology of the subject at hand. Besides, the question states "N dimensional array", not "N dimensional vector".

Comment: What is not straightforward in the decomposition? It is a bog-standard thing. To generate k small numbers in range [0..q), generate a big number in range [0..q^k), write it down in base q, and use the digits. There is nothing simpler and easier than that.

Comment: @JaMiT I dont want to say that his wording is good, I want to only explain it as somebody how know both sides.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thats the kind on calculation I would expect from the distribution class itself.

Comment: @gerum It is only viable if q is small, but a distribution class is not too likely to be fine-tuned specifically for small q. It might be, but it might be not. Of course one needs to experiment and find out if there's any gain.

Comment: @gerum, very fast, because this generation process may be run more than 10k times. (You can see I'm actually sampling for Monte-Carlo method, since the phase space is so big q^N, I need to sample a lot of times even in Markov chain Monte-Carlo method)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832817/why-float-division-is-faster-than-integer-division-in-c) integer division costs a lot, while PRNG mostly use fast instruction, so I'm judging between two.

Comment: @gerum Okaaay..... Thanks for explaining what I already know? My point is that the wording is not good. I kept my comment brief because I thought the OP knows enough to take it from there. If you think more explanation is needed by the OP, please direct it at the OP instead of me.

Comment: You won't need division if you pre-generate all k-digit base q numbers (i.e. all k-tuples of mod q integers) and use your prng to select a tuple. Of course that could be a lot of memory but you can choose k to be not too big. Or use a hybrid approach, chose k small, generate a number in range [0..q^2k), use a division once, and then use two halves of the number to index the tuple. In short, lots of fine tuning.

Comment: Physics simulation often takes shortcuts because otherwise the simulation would be prohibitive slow or not even possible at all. Do you really need to simulate *all* of the particles? Perhaps a few subsets are enough, and then extrapolate between the subsets? And what is your actual assignment? What is its requirements (and limitations)? Please [edit] your question to explain both the original problem you need to solve as well as detailing the requirements and limitations of the assignment.

Comment: Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). All to help you get up to date on how to improve your questions.

Comment: @PasserBy Having multiple RNGs is of course an easy solution, but how do you guarantee that the result is statistically as good as having one? I think for that you may need to think a little about where to set the seeds. Not trivial.

Comment: You may like to look into quantum computing, generating random numbers is the only thing they can do.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout True, I should've probably dropped the word "simply". But then again, seeding is difficult in general anyways.

Comment: @PasserBy Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the running time for a sequential initialization is prohibitive (for instance because it happens multiple times), you can indeed consider doing it in parallel. First of all, the C++ random number generation does not have global state, so you don't have to worry about thread-safety if you create a separate generator per thread.

However, you have to wonder independence. Clearly you can not start them all on the same seed. But picking random seeds is also dangerous. Just imagine what would happen if sucessive generators started on successive values in the sequence.

Here are two approaches:

1. If you know how many threads there are, say `p`, first start each generator at the same seed, and then thread `t` generates `t` numbers. That's the starting point. Now every time you need a new number, you take `p` steps! This means that the threads are using interlacing values from the random sequence.
2. On the other hand, if you know how many iterations `i` will happen in total, start each thread on the same seed, and then let thread `t` take `t * i` steps. So now each thread gets a disjoint block of values from the sequence.

There are other approaches to parallel random number generation, but these are simple solutions based on the standard sequential generator.

Comment: *"Just imagine what would happen if sucessive generators started on successive values in the sequence."* -- My imagination has produced a result that could potentially have been created if one generator was producing all the values (because for an ideal random number generator, no result is impossible, only improbable). Is there a reason to believe this result is more likely when seeding multiple generators with random seeds, then when using a single generator?

Comment: You should use a random number generator which is designed to be used in a parallel context. Look at Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3 - The Salmons (http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf) which has been implemented in various maths libraries.

Comment: @JimCownie The OP and I would appreciate if you would give a link to these various math libraries.

Comment: Google is your friend :-), it finds me, Intel MKL: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/statistical-functions/random-number-generators/basic-generators.html#:~:text=Philox4x32%2D10%20counter 
or this library for OpenCL, https://www.freshports.org/math/clrng#:~:text=MRG32k3a%2C%0ALFSR113%20and-,Philox%2D4x32%2D10,-generators.%0A%0AWWW%3A
Or this http://genn-team.github.io/genn/documentation/4/html/d5/d38/philox432_8c.html, etc...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-based_random_number_generator_(CBRNG) gives links to more.

Comment: @JimCownie Thanks. That page lists a bunch of generators that are supposed to be in the MKL VSL library, which I'm not familiar with. And several dozen clicks in I still haven't found the actual routine to call. So that's one proprietary library. Any others you'd recommend?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout  [This library](https://github.com/DEShawResearch/random123) cites the same paper JimCownie mentioned.

Comment: @Laci Thanks. That looks very promising.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I think the model is to create a stream, passing in the name of the underlying generator you want to use (which may need a search in the header file :-(). The two I pointed at both reference the Salmon11 paper. An example is at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/statistical-functions/random-number-generators/vs-rng-usage-modelintel-onemkl-rng-usage-model.html 
I will happily admit, though, that I haven't actually written such code myself...